# How to get the reason for "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."

Tags: android, google-play

I have built an app that has been published on Android Market. I get the `This app is incompatible with all of your devices.` message and would like to know if and how is possible to know the reason why this is not supported. I know that it could be a screen issue but it would be very useful to know the reason(s) for every single device. Is it possible?